Как сделать спойлер (скрытый текст) и цитату с помощью Aiogram?
message_text="hello world"
await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, caption = message_text, photo=photo, reply_markup=main_keyboard())

Как отправить слово world в спойлере а слово hello в цитате?

Наверное как то так:
message_text = "hello world".split(" ")
photo = FSInputFile('photo.jpg')
await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id,
                     caption=f'<blockquote>{message_text[0]}</blockquote>'
                             f'<span class="tg-spoiler">{message_text[1]}</span>',
                     photo=photo,
                     parse_mode="html")

Вывод выглядит так:


Спасибо большое!
